# How connect json file with after effects for rendering dynamic video

Tags: json, after-effects

I wan't to learn how connect some json file with after effects for rendering dynamic videos.

Eg i have a form in some webpage:

this form included one input which people are using there their name.

And then i create some json file like that array of objects with this form.

```
data = [
  {
   name: 'John'
  },
  {
   name: 'Mike'
  }
]
```

and i wan't to create with these json objects for each name some video about few second there will be shown just name from json and render some mp4 video.

How to do that?

which steps following? 
if it will be web form i think i'll need to connect json file dynamically too right?

so after effects will read this json file from some url ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to go about doing this, but a single answer on Stack Overflow probably won't give you everything you need.

Network communication can be done using the CEP framework provided by Adobe which can then execute ExtendScript code which actually does the manipulation of the layers inside the AEP project file.  You can use node modules to perform the network communication, and then write ExtendScript code to pass in the JSON data to that.

While not free, you might want to explore [Dataclay's Templater extension](https://dataclay.com/templater) to help you accomplish what you want.  It not only does what you are asking out of the box, but it has some rules-based AI to reconfigure layers both temporally and spatially.  You can point Templater to a URL that response with an array of JSON objects and have it process that data.  In addition to this, it has event hooks which allow you to execute any script within the Shell or with the ExtendScript engine during its versioning process.

Hope this helps!